# Using smoothscroll with gsap and magicScroll Pinned section

Tags: smooth-scrolling, gsap, scrollmagic

i'm using gsap with scroll magic to animate on my project i tried to implamente smoothscroll, it's working right ecxept for pinned section.

Any help plz ?

Comment: Given ScrollMagic hijacks normal scroll behavior, I'm guessing most smooth scroll scripts won't be compatible. In any case, please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue that you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way, or you do this without using scrollmagic ,baised on mouswheel & scrolling event

https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/PD21m

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/20873-smooth-scrolling-solution-that-supports-scrollmagic/

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17300-smooth-page-scroll/